# htaccess redirect url with trailing %20

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing

We use pretty urls on our site.  I had an external technician add back links some years ago.  He did a great job, but in one case, he consistently added a link with a trailing space character.

```
https://www.example.com/item/item/%20
```

This has been indexed as `%20` and I can see on my back link reports that there are 87 sites that point to the URL with `%20` at the end.

If I can redirect this, then my page `/item/item/` would gain 87 back links.

We use rewrite rules, and I have tried every solution here on stack overflow, but none has worked.  Some non working solutions are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*[^\ ])\ +$ /$1

RedirectRule (.*)\s$ $1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2
```

I have tried a redirect 301 but these don't work either.

```
redirect 301 /item/item/%20 /item/item/

redirect 301 /item/item/+ /item/item/
```

Some things that helps - this is not a site wide pattern. It is just one particular URL that got propagated out into the world incorrectly. And it is not a space anywhere in the string - it is always at the end.

Thanks.

It would also work fine for me to convert the trailing `%20` to a known character like a - because I could redirect it `/item/item/-` to `item/item/`

Comment: How is your server currently responding to these requests with a trailing _space_? A 403 Forbidden? How are these URLs routed? Is `/item/item/` entirely virtual or does it relate in some way to the filesystem?

Comment: It goes to our 404 page.  To be clear, the incoming link looks like /item/item/%20 and this is what is recorded on our site.  I think what confuses me is that htaccess rules work with the space translated, and in the htaccess syntax, a space is a delimiter.  Also normal URL encoding like + is not used either.

Comment: "htaccess rules work with the space translated" - Not necessarily. The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is %-decoded, however, not all server variables are. "a space is a delimiter" - if the argument contains a space then you can surround the entire argument in double quotes (or backslash escape the space - as you have done, or use `\s` shorthand character class in regex). "normal URL encoding like + is not used either" - The `+` (encoded space) only applies to the query string part of the URL. In the URL-path, a `+` is a literal `+` (plus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as your **topmost rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:\s|\x20)+$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Make sure you test in a new browser and Let me know if it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to work and is better than what I had found.